# Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT) in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

My code : https://pastebin.com/2pVActZv.

When I try to run the code, I get the following error:

```
Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 6021 (compatibility version 6000) but 
source was compiled with 4007 (compatibility version 4000).  If 
using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library to match.  If 
building from sources, make sure the library loaded at runtime 
matches a compatible version specified during compile configuration.
F tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc:457] Check failed: stream-
>parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms(&algorithms)
```

The tensorflow that I am using is 0.10.0rc0

I am using cuda 7.5.

What are the steps that I need to take to resolve the error?

OS : Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: Info on OS etc please.Note that CUDA Toolkit 8.0 or greater is required. cuNN 5.1 or greater is also required. Please try upgrading and see how you do. May I also suggest that if you are only just beginning with Tensorflow that you consider upgrading to the latest version. The pre-release version you are on will act differently to the most recent 1.x versions and has some differences. You will find support for that version much easier than 0.10. Of course, i understand that you might not be able to upgrade, but I recommend considering it.

Comment: @JCooke . I am working on ubuntu 16.10. Could you please guide me through the steps required to get the latest tensorflow gpu. The installation guide on tensorflow website is a bit difficult to follow.

Comment: You need to ensure that your requirements are met. I would use the links on the Tensorflow website to install them individually. I can't suggest much more than going through the installation steps for each of those. While they may seem complicated they are just tools and packages to install. nVidia provide their documentation for installing these as linked on the Tesnorflow website.

Comment: @JCooke I have now upgraded to the latest version. I am still getting the error. Could you try to run the script on your system?

Comment: Upgraded to the latest version of what? Tensorflow or your CUDA Requirements?

Comment: @JCooke Both Tensorflow and CUDA

Comment: I ran the code and it works fine. (Although you did have an error in your softmax section). The problem you are having here is that you have not installed Tensorflow GPU correctly. Please ensure you have correctly installed the required libraries. This includes adding items to your System PATH as specified in the instructions. I would recommend a fresh install of Tensorflow-gpu